# Apache pyspark How to create a column with array containing n elements

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 1 column of type integer.

I want to create a new column with an array containing n elements (n being the # from the first column)

For example:

```
x = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,),],StructType([ StructField("myInt", IntegerType(), True)])) 

+-----+
|myInt|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+
```

I need the resulting data frame to look like this:

```
+-----+---------+
|myInt|    myArr|
+-----+---------+
|    1|      [1]|
|    2|   [2, 2]|
|    3|[3, 3, 3]|
+-----+---------+
```

Note, It doesn't actually matter what the values inside of the arrays are, it's just the count that matters.

It'd be fine if the resulting data frame looked like this:

```
+-----+------------------+
|myInt|             myArr|
+-----+------------------+
|    1|            [item]|
|    2|      [item, item]|
|    3|[item, item, item]|
+-----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

It is preferable to avoid UDFs if possible because they are less efficient. You can use `array_repeat` instead.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

x.withColumn('myArr', F.array_repeat(F.col('myInt'), F.col('myInt'))).show()

+-----+---------+
|myInt|    myArr|
+-----+---------+
|    1|      [1]|
|    2|   [2, 2]|
|    3|[3, 3, 3]|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Note that I had some issues with it in spark 2.4.4 but it works fine in spark 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Use `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

@udf("array<int>")
def rep_(x):
    return [x for _ in range(x)]

x.withColumn("myArr", rep_("myInt")).show()
# +-----+------+
# |myInt| myArr|
# +-----+------+
# |    1|   [1]|
# |    2|[2, 2]|
# +-----+------+
```